# Cannot see service account of project in Dialogflow

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I created a project on google cloud platform, created a service account and generated a key. However, when I create an agent using that project on Dialogflow, I cannot see the service account listed. Any help with how I can achieve it?

Ultimately, I am trying to link it to chatbot on a Wordpress website.

Comment: Could you find it in the [APIs & Services→Credentials panel](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?_ga=2.168402209.1675202971.1615815822-1633620421.1612797851) in Cloud Console?

Comment: I can see it in there, yes.

Comment: Where couldn't you see the service account listed? could you share more detail?